# How to execute a while loop when wx.panel is shown?

Tags: python, while-loop, wxpython, panel, wxwidgets

I'm new using wxPython and I want to execute a while loop just when certain panel (Panel1) is shown and stop it when the panel gets hidden.

I'm interested in the loop because I want to change a label's value which is in the Panel1.

I tried to literally put the code `while True: ...`, but didn't work,

Any suggestions?

Comment: you best bet will be to start a thread and do what you want inside. Check the wxPython demo about the MT.

Comment: Depending on what you actually need, a timer might be just enough. Lookup Non-Blocking GUI or LongRunningTasks on wiki.wxpython.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, you can use a thread or a `wx.Timer` to accomplish what you're looking for. I grabbed some code from my old panel switching [tutorial](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/) and modified it to show how to use the timer approach. All you have to do is run the following code and switch the panels via the menu:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

########################################################################
class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(25,12)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.count = 0
        self.lbl = wx.StaticText(self,
                                 label='Counter: {}'.format(self.count))

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update, self.timer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def start_timer(self):
        self.timer.Start(1000)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def stop_timer(self):
        self.timer.Stop()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def update(self, event):
        self.count += 1
        self.lbl.SetLabel('Counter: {}'.format(self.count))

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Panel Switcher Tutorial")

        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
        self.panel_two.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        switch_panels_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,
                                                  "Switch Panels",
                                                  "Some text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSwitchPanels,
                  switch_panels_menu_item)
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSwitchPanels(self, event):
        """"""
        if self.panel_one.IsShown():
            self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
            self.panel_one.Hide()
            self.panel_two.Show()
            self.panel_two.start_timer()
        else:
            self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
            self.panel_one.Show()
            self.panel_two.stop_timer()
            self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Personally, I think using a thread for this is overkill. However it was kind of fun to modify the code above to use a thread instead. So here's that version too:

```
import time
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

from threading import Thread


########################################################################
class TestThread(Thread):
    """Test Worker Thread Class."""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, panel):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.panel = panel
        self.sentinel = True
        self.start()    # start the thread

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        # This is the code executing in the new thread.
        while self.sentinel:
            time.sleep(1)
            wx.CallAfter(self.panel.update)
        print 'Thread finished!'

########################################################################
class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(25,12)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.count = 0
        self.lbl = wx.StaticText(self,
                                 label='Counter: {}'.format(self.count))
        self.thread = None

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def start_timer(self):
        self.thread = TestThread(self)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def stop_timer(self):
        self.thread.sentinel = False

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def update(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.lbl.SetLabel('Counter: {}'.format(self.count))

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Panel Switcher Tutorial")

        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
        self.panel_two.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        switch_panels_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,
                                                  "Switch Panels",
                                                  "Some text")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSwitchPanels,
                  switch_panels_menu_item)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSwitchPanels(self, event):
        """"""
        if self.panel_one.IsShown():
            self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
            self.panel_one.Hide()
            self.panel_two.Show()
            self.panel_two.start_timer()
        else:
            self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
            self.panel_one.Show()
            self.panel_two.stop_timer()
            self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_close(self, event):
        self.panel_two.stop_timer()
        self.panel_two.thread.join()
        self.Destroy()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that you will want to catch the close event via `EVT_CLOSE` to make sure the thread is stopped when exiting your application or you may have your application hang or misbehave.

Comment: Thanks! It worked well. I totally forgot about threads. Thanks again :)